# Максимальное количество линий PCI Express

Tags: железо, cpu

Подскажите, если у чипсета 24 линии PCI-Ex, а у процессора 16 линий PCI-Ex, как они взаимосвязаны?

Может есть процессор поддерживающий такое же количество PCI-Ex линий, или все же линии в чипсете плюсуются к линиям в процессоре, что в итоге выходит 40 линий PCI-Ex?

По спецификации Intel Z270 чипсета: макс. кол-во каналов PCI Express - 24
https://ark.intel.com/ru/products/98089/Intel-Z270-Chipset

> Канал PCI Express (PCIe) состоит из двух пар каналов сигнализации, один из которых предназначен для приема, а другой - для передачи данных, и этот канал является базовым модулем шины PCIe. Число каналов PCI Express представляет собой общее число каналов, поддерживаемых процессором.

Вопрос стоит таким образом, чтобы выяснить, сколько слотов PCIe x1 может поддерживать материнская плата [PRIME Z270 A](https://www.asus.com/ru/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-A/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У данной платы 7 слотов PCIe x1 и два слота M.2, которые могут быть использованы как слоты PCIe x1 (но хватит ли линий PCI-Ex)

Answer (score 1):

Чипсет обычно работает как коммутатор, который связывает CPU с устройствами. 16 линий у процессора, фактически, означают, что вы можете подключать устройства х16 слотов к 16 линиям процессора. И, разумеется, сложение линий CPU и материнки бессмысленно.
8 видеокарт на данной мат. плате работают. 9 на Windows без особо изощренного шаманства, как я понимаю, запустить проблематично. Разве что пробовать карты разных производителей (речь о AMD/Nvidia), но всё равно пляски с бубном будут необходимы.